# i want to disabled column of saturday and sunday in my calender function

Tags: php, calendar

this is how my calender looks..[image] i have created calender using function.calender is worked properly but now i want to disabled saturday and sunday column of it. how can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

i have tried below code.

```
function draw_calendar($month,$year){

        if($month=='1')
        {
            $strmonth='january';
        }
        else if($month=='2')
        {
            $strmonth='february';
        }
        else if($month=='3')
        {
            $strmonth='march';
        }
        else if($month=='4')
        {
            $strmonth='april';
        }
        else if($month=='5')
        {
            $strmonth='may';
        }
        else if($month=='6')
        {
            $strmonth='june';
        }
        else if($month=='7')
        {
            $strmonth='july';
        }
        else if($month=='8')
        {
            $strmonth='august';
        }
        else if($month=='9')
        {
            $strmonth='september';
        }
        else if($month=='10')
        {
            $strmonth='october';
        }
        else if($month=='11')
        {
            $strmonth='november';
        }
        else if($month=='12')
        {
            $strmonth='december';
        }




    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar" align="center" ><tr><td align="center" colspan="7" style="border:1px solid gray;text-transform:uppercase;border-left:none;color:chocolate;height:30px;font-size:30px;padding:5px;"><b>'.$strmonth.'  &nbsp;  '.$year.'</b></td></tr>';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('<font color="red">Sunday</font>','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','<font color="red">Saturday</font>');

    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();


    /*  if(($headings[0]))
        { 
            $sday='style="color:red"'; 
        } 
        else
        {
            $sday='style="color:gray"'; 
        } 
    */


    /* row for week one */

    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row" >';


    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np" > </td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */

    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):

     if(isset($_SESSION['client']) && !empty($_SESSION['client']))
    {

        $s="select * from tbl_job_schedule where jobdate='".$strmonth."-".$list_day."-".$_SESSION['yy']."' and clientname='".$_SESSION['client']."'";

        $q=mysql_query($s) or die($s);
        $rw=mysql_fetch_array($q);
    }
    else if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $s="select * from tbl_job_schedule where jobdate='".$strmonth."-".$list_day."-".$_SESSION['yy']."' and username='".$_SESSION['user']."'";

        $q=mysql_query($s) or die($s);
        $rw=mysql_fetch_array($q);
    }


        if($rw['status']=='schedule')
        {
            $strimg='<img src="images/schedule.png" height="35" width="35"/>';
        }
        else if($rw['status']=='schwork')
        {
            $strimg='<img src="images/schedule.png" height="35" width="35"/>&nbsp;<img src="images/work.png" height="35" width="35"/>';
        }
        else if($rw['status']=='schworkcmnt' && $rw['client_cmnt']=='')
        {
            $strimg='<img src="images/schedule.png" height="35" width="35"/>&nbsp;<img src="images/work.png"height="35" width="35" />';
        }
        else if($rw['status']=='schworkcmnt' && $rw['client_cmnt']!='')
        {
            $strimg='<img src="images/schedule.png" height="35" width="35"/>&nbsp;<img src="images/work.png" height="35" width="35"/><br><img src="images/cmnt.png" height="35" width="35"/>';
        }
        else
        {
            $strimg='';
        }

        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day" onClick="OpenWin('.$list_day.');" >';

            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number" >'.$list_day.'</div><div style="height:90px;width:80px;border:0px solid yellow;float:right;padding-right:0px;padding-top:10px;" >'.$strimg.'</div><div style="height:40px;width:150px;padding:0px;border:0px solid yellow;float:left;margin-top:50px;margin-right:20px;font-size:14px;color:gray;text-transform:capitalize;" ><b>'.$rw['client_comp'].'</b></div>';

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

        $calendar.= '</td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;


}

/* sample usages */


?>
```

Comment: suggestion: instead of all the `if($month=='1')..else..else..` you can use `$strmonth = strtolower(date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1)));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//all other code. Check if date of the week equals 0-sunday or 6-saturday
if($running_day==0 || $running_day==6) {
$calendar.= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
} 
else
{
$calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day" onClick="OpenWin('.$list_day.');" >';
//... all other code
$calendar.= '</td>';
}
```

note: code not tested.